# extract string impala sql1

Tags: sql, impala

i have table like this:

testtime
4:6:7
11:2:8

how can i extract the minute and second from the string?
i want something like this:

testtime    minute    second
4:6:7       6       7
11:2:8      2       8

thanks

Comment: What code have you tried? What were the results?

Comment: Hi Mad Myche,i have tried with this code: regexp_extract('4:6:7',(\\d+)', 0), but the result is not correct

Comment: I generally recommending saving data and time as the proper data type and not as strings; in this case it would be as a  timestamp. Makes doing date/time functions a lot easier; such as the built in [date_part](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html#datetime_functions__date_part) function

Answer (score 1):

You can use Impala's `SPLIT_PART` function to do this pretty easily:

```
SELECT  SPLIT_PART("4:6:7", ":", 2),
        SPLIT_PART("11:2:8", ":", 2)
```

You just need to feed the function an input string, delimiter, and field number within the newly delimited string.